# Getting the table row values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the values from an HTML table row. When I click on the table row delete button, I want to put those values on variables to send to the server. I have found something from [here](http://jsbin.com/ihaqe6) that looks like what I need, but when I put it together for my scenario, it does not work.

Here is the table HTML:

```
  <table id='thisTable' class='disptable' style='margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'  >
    <tr>

   <th>Fund</th>
   <th>Organization</th>
   <th>Access</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class='fund'>100000</td><td class='org'>10110</td><td>OWNED</td><td><a  class='delbtn'ref='#'>X</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class='fund'>100000</td><td class='org'>67130</td><td>OWNED</td><td><a class='delbtn' href='#'>X</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class='fund'>170252</td><td class='org'>67130</td><td>OWNED</td><td><a class='delbtn' href='#'>X</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class='fund'>100000</td><td class='org'>67150</td><td>PENDING ACCESS</td><td><a  class='delbtn' href='#'>X</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class='fund'>100000</td><td class='org'>67120</td><td>PENDING ACCESS</td><td><a class='delbtn' href='#'>X</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
  var tr = $('#thisTable').find('tr');
        tr.bind('click', function(event) {
            //var values = '';
           // tr.removeClass('row-highlight');
            var tds = $(this).addClass('row-highlight').find('td');
            
            $.each(tds, function(index, item) {
                values = values + 'td' + (index + 1) + ':' + item.innerHTML + '<br/>';
                alert(values);
            });
            alert(values);

        });
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep looking at examples but I cant seem to make this work.

Comment: And what do you expect the output to be, from that HTML sample?

Comment: i expected the values from the row clicked to be alerted conctatenated. atleast to start.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('.delbtn').on('click', function() {
    var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
    var $columns = $row.find('td');

    $columns.addClass('row-highlight');
    var values = "";
    
    jQuery.each($columns, function(i, item) {
        values = values + 'td' + (i + 1) + ':' + item.innerHTML + '<br/>';
        alert(values);
    });
    console.log(values);
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/beME9/)

Comment: Thanks ricardo. I'm must appreciative for this answer. I was racking my brain for hours.

Comment: must people use $ instead of jQuery

Answer (score 7):

Give something like this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#thisTable tr").click(function(){
        $(this).find("td").each(function(){
            alert($(this).html());
        });
    });
});​
```

Here is a fiddle of the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/YhZsW/

Comment: I only want the function to give me the value of the clicked row not the entire table. this is where im getting stuck.

Comment: Hi, the fiddle and code has been updated :) I just changed "each" to "click"

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/hbpDm/1/).  I changed the code to output to a div instead of an alert box.  Your issue was `item.innerHTML` I believe.  I use the jQuery `html` function instead and that seemed to resolve the issue.

```
<table id='thisTable' class='disptable' style='margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'  >
    <tr>

   <th>Fund</th>
   <th>Organization</th>
   <th>Access</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class='fund'>100000</td><td class='org'>10110</td><td>OWNED</td><td><a  class='delbtn'ref='#'>X</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class='fund'>100000</td><td class='org'>67130</td><td>OWNED</td><td><a class='delbtn' href='#'>X</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class='fund'>170252</td><td class='org'>67130</td><td>OWNED</td><td><a class='delbtn' href='#'>X</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class='fund'>100000</td><td class='org'>67150</td><td>PENDING ACCESS</td><td><a  class='delbtn' href='#'>X</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class='fund'>100000</td><td class='org'>67120</td><td>PENDING ACCESS</td><td><a class='delbtn' href='#'>X</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="output"></div>​
```

the javascript:

```
$('#thisTable tr').on('click', function(event) {    
    var tds = $(this).addClass('row-highlight').find('td');
    var values = '';
    tds.each(function(index, item) {           
        values = values + 'td' + (index + 1) + ':' + $(item).html() + '<br/>';
    });
    $("#output").html(values);
});
```

Comment: sorry Jhon your solution did not work for me? im not sure why. I changed  $("#output").html(values);  to alert(values) and it does not do anything. Ricardo solution seems to do it thought.

Answer (score 0):

All Elements

```
$('#tabla > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find("td:gt(0)").each(function(){
       alert($(this).html());
       });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tbl_Customer tbody tr .companyname").click(function () {

            var comapnyname = $(this).closest(".trclass").find(".companyname").text();
            var CompanyAddress = $(this).closest(".trclass").find(".CompanyAddress").text();
            var CompanyEmail = $(this).closest(".trclass").find(".CompanyEmail").text();
            var CompanyContactNumber = $(this).closest(".trclass").find(".CompanyContactNumber").text();
            var CompanyContactPerson = $(this).closest(".trclass").find(".CompanyContactPerson").text();
           // var clickedCell = $(this);
            alert(comapnyname);
            alert(CompanyAddress);
            alert(CompanyEmail);
            alert(CompanyContactNumber);
            alert(CompanyContactPerson);

            //alert(clickedCell.text());
        });
    });
```

Comment: .companyname cell click part.  .trclass means tr class name .In find double quotation is each td class name ...It is working fine