# How to get row wise value from table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below table

```
<table id="grid_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="3" id="id_3" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="5.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="4" id="id_4" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="2.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery('table#grid_table input[type=input]').each( function(){  
    alert(jQuery(this).find('qty[]').val());
});
```

I'm able to get qty value.

How to get row wise if checkbox is checked then checkbox value & it's textbox value?

Comment: what is `qty[]` should it be `[name=qty[]]`

Comment: There are too many questions in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356497/get-the-table-row-data-with-a-click, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213335/getting-the-table-row-values-with-jquery

Comment: Did you see my answer? Wasn't the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Just change it on Page Load instead of Checkbox. Then will accept it @Mamun

Comment: I have changed the code. Please check snippet and let me know whether that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```js
$('table#grid_table tr').each( function(index, item){
   
   if($(item).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')){ 
      var chk = $(item).find('input:checkbox').val(); 
      console.log('Checkbox value at row '+index+': '+chk);
      var txt = $(item).find("input[name='qty[]']").val();
      console.log('Textbox value at row '+index+': '+txt);
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="grid_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="3" id="id_3" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="5.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="4" id="id_4" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="2.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```